# How to use Javascript as a backend script to make server side api calls without using HTML in Jint

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-phone-8.1, mobile-application

This [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/250819/how-to-develop-cross-platform-mobile-applications-with-native-ui-and-javascript) sets up the context for this question.

I am trying to use Javascript as the backend code for my mobile application(windows) which has a native UI(not HTML UI). That means I don't have HTML. Hence I don't have DOM.

I have successfully been able to create functions which does some computation locally like add, call them from my C# or Java code and get the return values.

Now I am running into 2 problems

1) I am trying to take my javascript functions one step further by trying to call server apis from the Javascript using XMLHttpRequest. But I am getting a script execution exception in my C#(This usually occurs if the script was unable to run). I think this is because XMLHttpRequest needs DOM and I don't have DOM.

If my first problem is solved then

2)How to get hold of a different Javascript file when I don't have DOM. For example let's say I want to use Jquery to simplify my requests using $.Ajax etc, but how do I load the Jquery library because I don't have the luxury of script tag neither do I have the luxury of using $.getScript because I am trying to get Jquery itself.

One possible solution

There is one solution that I can think on top of my head. Use a webview and load your html in the WebView and use Jint for Javascript. But then the question arises How do I use WebView in par with Jint.

I would be glad if someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to actually execute the JavaScript on the mobile devices?

Comment: @joeltine I have a Windows Application. So I am using Jint (https://jint.codeplex.com/) to run my javascript. This way I can call Javascript functions from my C# and vice versa.

Comment: @KevinB - That makes total sense. I have modified the question to make it generic by quoting Jquery as just an example.

Comment: It doesn't seem like Jint supports HTTP requests as a part of the JS interpreter. It does let you access .NET classes though: https://jint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20.NET%20classes%20from%20scripts&referringTitle=Documentation. I'm thinking that would allow you to access the device's network stack and communicate with the server through HTTP. But this kind of really defeats the purpose of "a single JS backend". In the end, you're going to end up writing custom logic for the platform you're on... just in JS.

Comment: @joeltine - That makes sense. Now I am thinking of using just the WebView use a blank html to load all my scripts and run the javascript in the mobile browser engine.